# Customizing and positioning a vertical slider in HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, cordova

I'm trying to create a remote control app using Cordova.

There should be 2 vertical sliders (`<input type="range">`, with my customizations (height, width, color, etc.). One should be on the left, positioned at 25% of the page width; and the other on the right, at 75% of the page width.

The sliders also should be centered on the correct point (ex. `calc(25% - 20px);` for the slider on the left if it is 40px wide, which it will be).

The only other requirement is that this webpage works on iOS Safari (really Cordova, but it uses Apple's WebKit which is basically the same). Opera/Firefox would also be nice. **It does not have to be IE compatible** (you're welcome).

I don't mind using Javascript/jQuery, but I would prefer CSS.

Also, for reasons unexplained, the sliders go off the top of the page, which must be fixed. One last bug with what I currently have is that applying `position: fixed; left: 0px;` to a slider does not move it completely to the left, so the `centerInViewport()` function is offset.

Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Coder256/6zjnk3qt/

I already tried `-webkit-appearance: slider-vertical`. It doesn't allow styling. For sliders, any `-webkit-appearance` value aside from `none` that I've tried doesn't let you style anything.

**UPDATE:** Sorry if I wasn't clear. The question is: How do I correctly position the sliders while keeping my customization, correctly being not too far up off the page and at the correct x position as described above?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @mark_c I updated the question.

Comment: Please explain why you downvoted if you did.

Comment: Maybe it's me, but i don't  completely understand the question even if you updated it.

Comment: You are already using a translateY, why not translate(-50%, -50%)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is to set `margin-top`to half of the sliders width to keep the sliders from being too far up off the page.

Same principle is for the x position. Use `calc` to set `left` to 25% / 75% minus half of the sliders width to get the correct position.

```css
html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.app {
  width: 100%;
}

.sliders {
  position: relative;
}

input[type=range].vslider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  transform: rotate(270deg) translateY(-50%);
  margin-top: 200px; /* 50% of the width because of the transformation */
  width: 400px;
  height: 40px;
  outline: none;
  position: absolute;
}

input[type=range].vslider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: #777;
  opacity: 0.75;
  width: 25px;
  height: 40px;
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}

input[type=range].vslider::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: #444;
  color: #444;
  height: 20px;
  width: 400px;
}

#LSlider {
  left: calc(25% - 200px); /* 50% of the width because of the transformation */
}

#RSlider {
  left: calc(75% - 200px); /* 50% of the width because of the transformation */
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <h1>RC Car Test</h1>
  <div id="sliders">
    <input type="range" min="-256" max="256" step="1" defaultValue="0" class="vslider" id="LSlider" />
    <input type="range" min="-256" max="256" step="1" defaultValue="0" class="vslider" id="RSlider" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible to add background color on the value?